# How do I get ASP.NET login status controls to display a Log In option?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, user-controls

I have the following log in status controls on the top of my master page. It displays the logged in as, manager log in, and Log out options.

However, when a user is not logged in, there is nothing displayed there. When the user is NOT logged in, is there a way to display a "Login" text link that takes you to the log in page and then "disappears" once the user is logged in?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
           <asp:LoginName ID="LoginName1" runat="server" FormatString="Logged in as {0}" ForeColor="Aqua" />

       <asp:LoginView ID="LoginView1" runat="server">
            <RoleGroups>
              <asp:RoleGroup Roles="Managers">
                 <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" 
                           NavigateUrl="~/Management/management.aspx">Manage Site</asp:HyperLink> or                    
                    <asp:LoginStatus id="LoginStatus1" runat="server" />                               
                 </ContentTemplate>
              </asp:RoleGroup>                      
           </RoleGroups>                     

           <LoggedInTemplate>  
              (<asp:LoginStatus id="LoginStatus1" runat="server" />)
           </LoggedInTemplate> 

       </asp:LoginView>
```

ASP.NET 3.5
VWD 2008
C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [AnonymousTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.loginview.anonymoustemplate.aspx).